# Restrict access on a mounted device (Linux)

Tags: linux, device, mount

The challenge is to allow access to only one directory on the mounted device for all users.

I have an external hard drive. I mount it using the command

```
sudo mount -o umask=0007,gid=0,uid=0 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/SAMSUNG/
```

I need to make one directory available for reading/writing to other users on this device. I cannot do this via **sudo chmod 777 /mnt/SAMSUNG/my_directory**, the command has no effect.

Is there some other way to do this? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the file system type on your device ? Result of "cat /proc/mounts" or "cat /proc/$$/mountinfo" ?

Comment: @RachidK. I am connecting NTFS. Most likely it does not support access control when mounting, right?

Comment: Look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Comment: @RachidK. In fact - the same thing that I do ... Only I need to set the rules for one specific directory, and here it turns out - all directories will have the same rules. On the contrary, I need to restrict access to other directories on the mounted device. NTFS will not allow me to do this, apparently ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mounting the NTFS file system (*/mnt/SAMSUNG/*), there is no possibility of mounting a specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your `sudo chmod 777 /mnt/SAMSUNG/my_directory` command you give

- The user, rwx (Read, Write and Execute) permissions
- The group, rwx permissions
- And Everyone else rwx permissions

Inside of **/mnt/SAMSUNG/my_directory** is the thought that there should be more directories that is specific for other accounts?

If that is the case and the users are local you could do something like this:

`sudo chown someuser:someuser /mnt/SAMSUNG/my_directory/someusersdir && sudo chmod 770 /mnt/SAMSUNG/my_directory/someusersdir`

Comment: The commands are executed without error, but there is no result. It feels like they DO NOT APPLY due to the fact that I set a specific mount mask.

Comment: If you do `ls -l /mnt/SAMSUNG/` you should see something like this `drwx------+  7 <someuser>  <somegroup>   224 Jan  4 12:57 Documents` In my case, it is a directory "Documents" and there is a rwx permission on it.

Comment: Commands like `chmod` and `chown` doesn't give any output after they have been executed unless there isn't a syntax error.